# safari 10.1 es6 module example

Tags: javascript, typescript, safari, ecmascript-6

I made a index.html page with this in it

`<script type="module" src="scripts/index.js"></script>`

index.js contains

`import 'menu';`

And Release 26 (Safari 10.2, WebKit 12604.1.12) is complaining

`TypeError: Module specifier does not start with "/","./","../"`

What am I doing wrong?

Note that typescript is not complaining when I compile index.ts to index.js

Worst case scenario for me is that TypeScript and Safari 10.1 want different import syntax that would $%^*^(&)(*!!! for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After more testing I am almost certain that Safari 10.1 wants `import './menu.js';` not `import 'menu';`

Trying to convince TypeScript to make a module compiler option for it.

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14861

Comment: This is correct. Modules in the browser must import URLs, either absolute or relative, and relative URLs must start with `.` or `..`. (The idea is that semantics for "naked" imports can be reserved now, and defined later.)